# MaxSteps and Computing time issue for Solving Differential equation in Mathematica

Tags: performance-tuning, numerics, differential-equations

When we solve differential equation numerically using `NDSolve` then sometimes we get error like **NDSolve::mxst:** *Maximum steps reached*

According to Mathematica docs the solution is to increase `MaxSteps`. For example if you used `MaxSteps -> 100` and limit of x 0 to 100 but Mathematica calculated up to the `x=50` then increasing steps `MaxSteps -> 200`  will solve your problem.

My problem is what i got from mathematica is -

```
During evaluation of In[212]:= NDSolve::mxst: 
     Maximum number of 10000 steps reached 
     at the point x == 2.1685790754404513`*^-14.
```

So even if i want to got from limit 0 to 2 for `x` then my steps should be 10^14 times larger. It will take a huge huge computing time. How much it may take for core i3 processor? **Is there any other way to compute quickly or solve this problem of maxsteps in any other way?**

My ODE:

```
v[x_] := {v1[x], v2[x]} ;
ini = v[0] == {1, 0};  
soln = NDSolve[LogicalExpand[I v'[x] == H.v[x] && ini], {v1, v2}, {x, x1, x2}]
```

where H is matrix

Comment: Can you give the *actual* problem you're trying to solve? What you've mentioned isn't sufficient for us to help you.

Comment: @J.M.  Thanks. But actual problem is large. Other part of the problem is actually about the construction and taking Matrix H to its final form. without construction of H its just these tree lines of codes and plotting. Then... I need to send you the whole file you need see actual thing.

Comment: Then I suppose you could upload your *Mathematica* notebook to some file host like [Sendspace](http://www.sendspace.com/) or [iFile](http://ifile.it/).

Comment: The largest eigenvalue of `H` is about `7.4*10^16` which would mean that you'll get a highly oscillatory solution with a wavelength of about `10^-16` so I guess you would need a step size `< 10^-18` or so (and you would need to worry about `PrecisionGoal` and `WorkingPrecision`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`NDSolve` uses adaptive methods to obtain a good solution.  It dynamically changes the step size during integration.

I recommend you take a look at the [Advanced Numerical Differential Equation Solving](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveOverview.html) tutorial (ODE section), which has a *very* detailed description of how `NDSolve` work, what methods are available, and how you can tweak them.

You can start with

```
NDSolve[..., Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitEuler"}, StartingStepSize ->  ... ]
```

to figure out what is going on (this will likely not give you a precise solution though).  There's a good chance that your differential equation is very troublesome to solve, so automatic method selection will not work well.  In this case you'll need to study the methods available, and make a suitable choice yourself.