# Controlling the time step in NDSolve?

Tags: numerical-integration, differential-equations, options, reference-request

I generally use NDSolve for stiff non linear partial differential equations of 4th order. I find that a BDF1 method generally does well to placate my beast of a PDE.

I've also tried out `"MaxSteps"` to curtail my simulation to a certain number of time steps.

I understand that BDF and other methods for stiff equations are adaptive time step methods and I notice that `"Fixed"` step is not a valid option for BDF at least. Is there any way I could solve stiff equations with a fixed time step? I realize that NDSolve knows best but it would give me more flexibility to play around with the wonderful options in NDSolve if there were a way to use fixed time steps.

**> My references:**

[this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/863/204) and [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveFixedStep.html)

**> This is how I tried using `"FixedStep"`:**

`Method -> {"FixedStep", "Method" -> {"BDF", "MaxDifferenceOrder" -> 1}}`

Obviously this was incorrect as `"BDF"` isn't a submethod.

Comment: According to the documentation FixedStep only works with one-step integration methods, while I think BDF is/are multistep methods. So I think the problem is that BDF is not a _valid_ submethod for FixedStep...

Comment: @AlbertRetey sure. I understand that. But even adaptive time step methods are predicated on some condition. How do I control that condition? I am guessing in this case, its a stiffness-stability criterion that decides the time step. Is there some way I can *look* at the Jacobian matrix from `NDSolve[...]`? Anyone?

Comment: Sorry, I just wanted to express that I don't know any way to do what you want -- and tried to point out the fact that the documentation says that what you look for is probably not implemented, for reasons not uncovered...

Comment: @AlbertRetey sure thing man! No beef! `:P` It would be great to figure a way out to actually meddle with the internals of mathematica like one can do with say `ode15` in `MATLAB`! Thanks for helping!

Comment: actually I haven't been of much help yet :-). Just as a final remark: while the documentation says that `FixedStep` and `BDF` don't work together, I think that the `NDSolve`-framework should in principle allow to do something like that (after all you can define completely new `Methods`). The question is whether you are willing to spend the effort to implement that -- it would certainly be more effort than I can spend for an answer, sorry.

Comment: @AlbertRetey Do you think there is a way to *see* what the Jacobian looks like though?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. I think it would mean to read `tutorial/NDSolvePlugIns` and `tutorial/NDSolveStateData` carefully and play with everything written there. As I have never actually written an `NDSolve`-method myself, I just can guess, but I think it probably would be easiest to use the example about the classical Runge-Kutta method with a fixed step size and adopt it. Trying to make use of the existing `BDF` and write a fixed step controller method for it might need some reverse engineering of undocumented code, if it is possible at all...

Answer (score 11):

To get a fixed step size with the BDF method you can lower the `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` to increase the adaptive step sizes and then use `MaxStepSize` to limit the step size to any value you want.

Get an example stiff system from the documentation:

```
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveProblems`"];
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveUtilities`"];
system = GetNDSolveProblem["VanderPol"];
```

Solve with the `BDF` method:

```
sols = NDSolve[system, {T, 0, 10}, Method -> "BDF"];
Plot[Evaluate[sols[[1, All, 2]]], {T, 0, 10.}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Plot the step sizes:

```
StepDataPlot[sols] /. AbsolutePointSize[_] -> PointSize[Small]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Solve again with low precision and accuracy goals and small `MaxStepSize`:

```
sols = NDSolve[system, {T, 0, 10}, Method -> "BDF", 
  PrecisionGoal -> 0, AccuracyGoal -> 0, MaxStepSize -> 1. 10^-5
];
Plot[Evaluate[sols[[1, All, 2]]], {T, 0, 10.}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now we have a fixed step size:

```
StepDataPlot[sols] /. AbsolutePointSize[_] -> PointSize[Small]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can increase the step size, but the result starts to diverge from the true solution:

```
sols2 = NDSolve[system, {T, 0, 10}, Method -> "BDF", 
   PrecisionGoal -> 0, AccuracyGoal -> 0, MaxStepSize -> 1. 10^-4
];
Plot[Evaluate[Flatten[{sols, sols2}][[All, 2]]], {T, 0, 10.}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We still have a fixed step size, though:

```
StepDataPlot[sols2] /. AbsolutePointSize[_] -> PointSize[Small]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Very neat! Would you mind telling how you figured out that lowering those settings did the trick?

Comment: @Guesswho I've spent a lot of time using the BDF solver from the [Sundials suite](https://computation.llnl.gov/casc/sundials/main.html), which may be used by Mathematica as well (at least it is in the [case of DAEs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveIDAMethod.html)). There the adaptive step size is directly controlled by the precision and accuracy tolerances -- you can make the steps as large as you want by increasing the tolerances.