# Kinetic Friction in Mathematica, weird behaviour

Tags: differential-equations

I found the behavoiur of Sign function weird in the code below.

when $T=10$

```
T = 10;
A = 1;
Fk0 = 2;
m1 = 1;
x0[t_] = A Sin[2 Pi t];
Fk[t_] = -Fk0  Sign[x1'[t]];
sol = NDSolve[{
  m1 x1''[t] == -m1 x0''[t] + Fk[t], x1'[0] == 10, x1[0] == 0}, 
 {x0, x1}, {t, 0, T}, MaxSteps -> Infinity]
Plot[{x0''[t], x1'[t] /. sol // Evaluate}, {t, 0, T}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

but when $T=40$
, I got
[image]
which is how it is supposed to be. I wonder what I did wrong here.

Comment: no errors/warnings?

Comment: It returns no error.

Answer (score 5):

Using `WhenEvent[]` to get a typical kinetic friction behavior:

```
A = 1;
m1 = 1;
x0[t_] := A Sin[2 Pi t];
Fk0 = m1;
Fk[t_] := -Fk0 a[t];
sol[T_?NumericQ] := 
 NDSolve[{m1 x1''[t] == -m1 x0''[t] + Fk[t], x1'[0] == 10, x1[0] == 0, a[0] == 1,
         WhenEvent[x1'[t] == 0, a[t] -> Sign[x1'[t]]]}, {a, x1}, {t, 0, T}, 
         MaxSteps -> Infinity, DiscreteVariables -> a, MaxStepSize -> 10^-3]
GraphicsRow@{
       Plot[{x0''[t], x1[t] /. sol[10], x1'[t] /. sol[10]}, {t, 0, 10}, Frame -> True,
             Evaluated -> True,  PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green}],
       Plot[{x0''[t], x1[t] /. sol[40], x1'[t] /. sol[40]}, {t, 0, 40}, 
            Frame -> True, Evaluated -> True, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green}]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: It could be interesting to add a static friction component at those instants when `x1'[t]==0`

Comment: does `WhenEvent` detect a sign change, or only trigger if the numerical value is precisely zero?

Comment: @george2079 You can adjust the detection method by using options, but NDSolve being a numerical method implementation can't rely in exact values

Comment: @george2079 I believe it detects a sign change.

Comment: @george2079: it is documented to detect sign changes: "f==0: the function f of the solution variables crosses zero" (from ref/WhenEvent).

Comment: When I put `a[t]/.sol` on the plot it seems to sometimes catch some of sign changes ??.  I'd advise taking a real careful critical look at this result if it is something important.

Comment: @george2079 `NDSolve` is a numerical method and `WhenEvent`, at its current form, is notoriously famous to seem to work, but actually to miss events in many systems. Maybe this gets better on Mma 10, where it is claimed to work also with `DSolve`.

Answer (score 5):

As it turns out the only thing wrong with the original solution is a stroke of bad luck..
Once you hit the zero point at 5, the default time step is one and the solution marches out values at 6,7,8,9,10.. where the forcing function is zero..

Simply limiting the step size fixes things..

```
 T = 10;
 A = 1;
 Fk0 = 2;
 m1 = 1;
 x0[t_] = A Sin[2 Pi t];
 Fk[t_] = -Fk0 Sign[x1'[t]];
 sol = NDSolve[{m1 x1''[t] == -m1 x0''[t] + Fk[t], x1'[0] == 10, 
                x1[0] == 0}, {x0, x1}, {t, 0, T}, MaxSteps -> Infinity, 
                MaxStepSize -> .01]
 Plot[{x0''[t], x1'[t], 10 Sign[x1'[t]]} /. sol, {t, 0, T}, 
          Evaluated -> True, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Here is the original showing the actual solution points..

```
Show[{Plot[x1'[t] /. sol, {t, 0, T}, Evaluated -> True, Frame -> True],
    Graphics[{PointSize[.01], 
    Point@{#, x1'[t] /. First@sol /. t -> # } & /@ 
         First@Cases[sol, f_InterpolatingFunction, Infinity][[1, 3]]}]}]
```

[image]

By the way there is a cleaner way to display the solution points using `EvaluationMonitor` described in the documentation.

Comment: In v8.0.4, `MaxStepSize -> .01` doesn't work, but `MaxStepSize -> .03` does. I think that a more strict control for the step is needed, though I don't know how to achieve that…

Comment: yes 9.0.1.  I find it frankly a bit disturbing that the default time step algorithm has made such a poor choice here abruptly jumping by a factor of ~1000. There should be a way to limit the change in time step instead of just setting an absolute limit but I can't readily see a way.

Comment: I found it, see the 3rd approach in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

*Dadan Ari Wibowo*, *george2079* and *belisarius* are all in v9, right? With this question, I noticed some slight changes are made for `NDSolve` in v9.

The syntax of `NDSolve` in OP's code is incorrect for v8.0.4. `x0`, as a known function, isn't allowed to be the 2nd argument of `NDSolve`.

Then the behavior of `NDSolve` at $t=5$ is different:

```
T = 6;
A = 1;
Fk0 = 2;
m1 = 1;
x0[t_] = A Sin[2 Pi t];
Fk[t_] = -Fk0 Sign[x1'[t]];
sol = NDSolve[{m1 x1''[t] == -m1 x0''[t] + Fk[t], x1'[0] == 10, x1[0] == 0}, x1, {t, 0, T}]
Plot[{x0''[t], x1'[t] /. sol // Evaluate}, {t, 0, T}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Notice that the option `MaxSteps -> Infinity` has been removed or it'll eat up all my computer memory.

Finally, I've found 3 solutions for this problem. The 1st one is to use option `WorkingPrecision -> 16`:

```
sol = NDSolve[{m1 x1''[t] == -m1 x0''[t] + Fk[t], x1'[0] == 10, x1[0] == 0}, 
              x1, {t, 0, T}, WorkingPrecision -> 16]
Plot[{x0''[t], x1'[t] /. sol // Evaluate}, {t, 0, T}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

I have to mention that **only** `WorkingPrecision -> 16` will work in this case i.e. even `WorkingPrecision -> 15` or `WorkingPrecision -> 17` will generate the same error. This solution is probably a coincidence caused by numerical error so it's not that instructive.

The 2nd approach is to use `Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"`:

```
sol = NDSolve[{m1 x1''[t] == -m1 x0''[t] + Fk[t], x1'[0] == 10, x1[0] == 0}, 
              x1, {t, 0, T}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"]
Plot[{x0''[t], x1'[t] /. sol // Evaluate}, {t, 0, T}, Frame -> True]
(* The plot is same as the former so I'd like not to "repost" it. *)
```

I found this approach mainly by… er… intuition so I can't give a theoretical explanation for it. (From the failing plot we see that something seems to happen at zero point so I guess it might be a stiffness issue and it seems to be! ) Maybe someone more experienced in `NDSolve` can give a detailed instruction?

Inspired by [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/863/1871), I've found the 3rd solution:

```
sol = NDSolve[{m1 x1''[t] == -m1 x0''[t] + Fk[t], x1'[0] == 10, x1[0] == 0}, x1, {t, 0, T}, 
              Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta"}, 
              StartingStepSize -> 1, MaxStepFraction -> Infinity]
(* Plot[{x0''[t], x1'[t] /. sol // Evaluate}, {t, 0, T}, Frame -> True] *)
<< "DifferentialEquations`NDSolveUtilities`"
StepDataPlot[sol]
```

[image]

Here I deliberately chose `1` as the step size so all of the zero point should have been hit, but correct result is still generated, so it's hard (at least for me) to tell what actually happened inside `NDSolve`, after all, it's one of the most complex functions in *Mathematica*.

Not sure if my 3 approaches will work for v9.